# Is it possible to use Docker Toolbox on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: docker, windows-10, visual-studio-code, docker-toolbox

I have Windows 10 Home edition, therefore I had to install Docker Toolbox instead of Docker. I am using Visual Studio Code for development and it has extension for Docker Support (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docker) which adds integration for the most common Docker commands.

Unfortunately it does not work in my case (output from Visual Studio Code terminal):

```
C:\Users\Konrad\workspace\docker-tests>docker build . -t docker-whale
An error occurred trying to connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cgr
oupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory
=0&memswap=0&rm=1&shmsize=0&t=docker-whale&ulimits=null: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the
 file specified.
```

The same command works just fine in Docker Quickstart Terminal.

Is it possible to configure Visual Studio Code to use docker in the same way as "Docker Quickstart Terminal" does? I should change some system configuration to be able to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran through the same issue. Following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/docker/building-net-docker-images) I was able to use Yeoman to configure a dotnet core container and then when you hit F5, VS Code generates the image for your app within the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you have Docker Toolbox in your machine.

Use **VSCode Remote Container** development. 
You can find more information here: [How to use vscode remote containers with Docker Toolbox (Windows 7)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430679/how-to-use-vscode-remote-containers-with-docker-toolbox-windows-7/59430680#59430680)